# Animation with initial/after state

Tags: angular, animation, angular-animations

I'm trying to sort through how to do an Angular animation with an initial state. I'm trying to develop a slide up/down animation, so far with:

```
trigger(
    'slideHeight',
    [
        state('closed', style({
            display: 'none',
            height: 0
        })),
        state('open', style({
            // display: 'block',
            height: '*'
        })),
        transition('* <=> *', [
            style({
                display: 'block'
            }),
            animate('.5s ease')
        ])
    ]
)
```

In the jQuery version, the element in question has `display: none` on it, and I notice that jQuery slides open, and then I see `display: block` on the final element.

When I have `display: 'block'` commented out as above, it works as expected, however, when the page loads, it starts with the elements going from full height to none (which makes sense I guess?), which is weird for the user.

I'm trying to figure out how I can set it up so when closed, first it goes to `display: block`, runs the height animation, and holds block. In the other direction, I want to have block until it's done, adding a `display: none`.

I've tried adding a class with display none, but as animations don't add a class before/after, it didn't quite work as expected. I suspect this should be a combination of the Angular animation JS and CSS classes, but I can't quite figure out the pattern. Any advice in how to address this would be great.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want, but you can use `*` to describe a state which is the 'default' state. I see you're already doing this with height but you can define a state as `*` too.

I want to be able to show and hide an arrow. So it has two logical states 'in' and 'out'. That's easy enough switching between the two. But if the initial state should be 'in' then I want it to fade in, but there won't be a 'starting point' for the `out => in` animation or even `* => in` unless you define a `*` state.

```
 animations: [
    trigger('showArrow',
    [            
        state('*', style({opacity: 0})),
        state('in', style({opacity: 1})),
        state('out', style({opacity: 0})),

        transition('* => in', [
           animate(15000)    
        ]),

        transition('* => out', [
            animate(200)
        ])
    ])
  ],
```

So my icon is defined like this (note that this is a custom svg):

```
<mat-icon [@showArrow]="(showArrow$ | async) ? 'in' : 'out'"
          svgIcon="right-arrow"></mat-icon>
```

Even if the initial state is hardcoded to `true` (so there is no state change as such) it will still fade in because I've defined a `*` starting state (with 0 opacity).

```
    this.showArrow$ = new BehaviorSubject(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need two transitions to get what you want.

```
trigger(
    'slideHeight',
    [
        state('closed', style({
            display: 'none',
            height: 0
        })),
        state('open', style({
            height: '*'
        })),
        transition('closed => open', [style({ display: none }), animate('.5s ease')]),
        transition('open => closed', [style({ display: 'block' }), animate('.5s ease')])
    ]
)
```

Comment: I actually don't want the intermediary style to ever be none, but I'm actually noticing that I can't get the intermediary styles to apply: https://plnkr.co/edit/7c23w3GNeYAPlGl6KUgB (if you inspect the box while it's animating, it never applies any intermediary styles).